# Conexion C# con PostgreSQL mediante proveedor Npgsql

Tags: c#, postgresql

Hola el problema es que la conexión esta bien solo cuando estoy utilizando el `ODBC`, pero cuando lo cambio al proveedor de `PostgreSQL Npgsql`, ya no me deja conectar me dice que error de sintaxis, yo creo que el error es en la linea de conexion:

```
try {

-->  NpgsqlConnection cn = new NpgsqlConnection("SERVER=localhost; UID=postgres;PWD=damaris;DATABASE=ProyectoAsistenciaCCB;");

    cn.Open();

    NpgsqlCommand cmd = new  NpgsqlCommand("INSERT INTO reportes VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",cn);

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Clear();

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@p1", NpgsqlDbType.Numeric).Value = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[0].Value);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cn.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sería apreciado que formatees tu pregunta para que sea legible para futuros lectores también. En este momento, el código no se puede leer correctamente. Y siempre es bueno que seas específico en cuanto al error que tuvistes, y en qué línea. Nuevamente, se trata de beneficiar a los futuros lectores también.

Comment: ok gracias lo tendre en cuenta

Comment: Mucho mejor. Pero aun falta que especifiques **cuál línea** produce el error.  Y de paso, te aviso que debe ser un error el que tengas `cn.Close()` **adentro** del `foreach`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta pregunta es un buen ejemplo del por qué es sumamente importante que incluyas toda la información pertinente en tu pregunta, incluyendo el mensaje de error **exacto**, y también el **stack trace**.

De haberlo hecho, hubiera sido claro desde el principio que el error no tiene nada que ver con la conexión de base de datos. Mas bien, tu error sucede al ejecutar:

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); // verifica que de aquí viene tu error.
```

Y la razón del error es que no le gusta el SQL, particularmente el símbolo `?` que usas para los parámetros:

```sql
INSERT INTO reportes VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Con `Npgsql`, los parámetros deben pasarse usando la sintaxis siguiente (los nombres que escojas no tienen mayor importancia, siempre y cuando uses `@` en frente):

```sql
INSERT INTO reportes VALUES(@p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5)
```

El siguiente problema que tienes es que solo le pasas un parámetro a la sentencia (`@p1`). Pero ¿qué hay de los 4 otros valores que el `INSERT` necesita?

Y finalmente, no tiene sentido que ejecutes `cn.Close()` dentro del `foreach`. Piénsalo bien, y verás por qué. De hecho, no hay necesidad de ejecutar `cn.Close()` explícitamente si usas [`using`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/yh598w02.aspx) para instanciar la conexión a la base de datos. Esto es mejor práctica, y te protege de situaciones de errores que pueden resultar en que la conexión nunca se cierre.

Te dejo un modelo a lo que debería parecerse tu código para que funcione correctamente:

```
using(var cn = new NpgsqlConnection("SERVER=localhost; UID=postgres;PWD=damaris;DATABASE=ProyectoAsistenciaCCB;"))
{
    cn.Open();

    using(var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("INSERT INTO reportes VALUES(@p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5)", cn))
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@p1", NpgsqlDbType.Numeric).Value = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[0].Value);

            // Solo un ejemplo, pero necesitas pasar los 4 siguientes parámetros también...
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@p2", NpgsqlDbType.Numeric).Value = ???;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@p3", NpgsqlDbType.Numeric).Value = ???;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@p4", NpgsqlDbType.Numeric).Value = ???;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@p5", NpgsqlDbType.Numeric).Value = ???;

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ok perdon no supe como plasmar mi error  entonces ya no es necesario poner un try{  }catch{  ???

Comment: Lo que puse es solo un modelo. En el código de tu pregunta, no hay `catch`, así que no puedo juzgar si es necesario o no.  Nuevamente, la intención de mi respuesta es de ayudarte a identificar tu problema y darte ideas para mejorar el código. Pero tu tienes que investigar el asunto a fondo para saber lo que es apropiado en tu caso.

Comment: ok pues muchas gracias mi es de mucho apoyo tu comentario gracias

Comment: [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Según la documentación de Npgsl el formato es el siguiente:

```
NpgsqlConnection("Host=myserver;User Id=mylogin;Password=mypass;Database=mydatabase"))
```

Prueba a reemplazar UID y PWD por Username y Password.

http://www.npgsql.org/doc/connection-string-parameters.html

Comment: ok deja cambiarlo

Comment: @karol: Si esta respuesta te ayudó a resolver tu problema, sería una muestra de aprecio que le des un voto a favor, y que además la marques como aceptada (haz click en el "check" a la izquierda de la respuesta). Gracias.

Comment: hola mmm no aun sigue el error me dice que error de sintaxis

Comment: @karolprincess puedes hacer un paste de la sentencia?

Comment: de cual? .......

Comment: de la ConnectionString que te da el error de sintaxis

Comment: NpgsqlConnection cn = new NpgsqlConnection("SERVER=localhost; UID=postgres;PWD=damaris;DATABASE=ProyectoAsistenciaCCB;");

Comment: @karolprincess no has cambiado nada???

Comment: oh si perdon es este:   NpgsqlConnection cn = new NpgsqlConnection("Host=localhost; Username=postgres;Password=1234;Database=ProyectoAsistencia;");

Comment: entiendo que el error se produce al realizar el .Open(), si es asi una prueba mas, cambia username por User Id.  NpgsqlConnection("Host=myserver;User Id=mylogin;Password=mypass;Database=mydatabase"))

Comment: am sigue el error me dice error de sintaxis o cerca de <<,>>

Comment: Estas separando los parametros de NpgsqlConnection con , (comas) en vez de ; (punto y coma) ?

Comment: no, los tengo separados por ;

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47340/discussion-between-karolprincess-and-mcnets).